# Java ResultSet Skipping Records

Tags: java, mysql

After a morning of research, I'm stumped on what should be an easy piece of code.

All I want is to get all records from our raw_material table in the test database.

Here is what I am doing:

```
public static void fetchIthos(ArrayList<String> ithosList, UserDto user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //get our stuff first - raw materials and doc names and paths
    try {

        Connection conn = user.getConnection();
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM raw_material where object_id > 0");

        do {
        String result = rs.getString("raw_material_number").toString();
        System.out.println("next item: " + result);
        //ithosList.add(rs.getString("raw_material_number"));
        } while(rs.next());
    }

     catch (Exception e) {
       ithosList.equals(null);
        System.out.println("DB error : " + e);
     }
}
```

Here are the results in mySQL:

[image: Result]

so I would expect the first 'result' to be `MAN-500-121200000`, but it is showing as `RAW-001485`

I cannot see anywhere in the code that I am 'skipping' the first record, but if I let it go, it will skip the next one to `MAN-500-056100000`

Am I using the wrong user connection? That is the only thing I can see that affects this.

I thought `user.getConnection()` would do it for just the regular test database.

Comment: `ithosList.equals(null);` doesn't do anything. That method call returns true if `ithosList` is `null`, false otherwise.

Comment: I haven't gotten around to coding that piece yet. I want the right results before I add to an arraylist.

Comment: If you execute `ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM raw_material where object_id > 0");` twice, is there any guarantee that the results will be returned in the same order?

Comment: I can't imagine why it wouldn't return in the right order. I did add an 'order by object_id asc, still the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void fetchIthos(ArrayList<String> ithosList, UserDto user) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i = 1;
    //get our stuff first - raw materials and doc names and paths
    try {

        Connection conn = user.getConnection();
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsCount = st.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) from raw_material");
        rsCount.first();
        long r = (Long) rsCount.getObject(i);

        for (i=1; i < r+1; i++) {

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM raw_material where object_id =" + i + "");

            //moves to the first record
            rs.first();

            do {
                String result = rs.getString("raw_material_number");
                System.out.println("next item: " + result);
                ithosList.add(rs.getString("raw_material_number"));
            } while(rs.next());
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        ithosList.equals(null);
        System.out.println("DB error : " + e);
    }

}
```

Hacky way of doing it but it got it to work for now, at least until the senior developer returns from bereavement. Keep in mind I've had only 3 months of java, baptism by fire. lol.

Answer (score 4):

Your code seems to be incorrect, the expected loop is rather:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    String result = rs.getString("raw_material_number");
    System.out.println("next item: " + result);
}
```

Consider using [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) statement to close properly your `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` as next:

```
try (Connection conn = user.getConnection();
     Statement st = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM raw_material where object_id > 0")) {
    // My code here
}
```

Comment: This is definitely right, although it seems odd that it would skip the first result. In fact, I seem to remember getting error messages if you don't advance the cursor but that could be implementation dependent.

Comment: 'while(rs.next()) {
    String result = rs.getString("raw_material_number");
    System.out.println("next item: " + result);
}'     


Still returning RAW-001485

Comment: @PaulaAnneMcGrath you don't get MAN-500-121200000 at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
while(rs.next()){
  String result = rs.getString("raw_material_number");
  System.out.println("next item: " + result);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `.toString()` on what is, already, a `String`?